# Custom JLabel icon

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlabel, imageicon

I want to use java JLabel with an Icon in custom size on my GUI. like this :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVglU.png]

I used this code to change size of original Icon :

```
    ImageIcon imageIcon = (ImageIcon) jLabel1.getIcon();// new ImageIcon( "Play-Hot-icon.png");

    ImageIcon thumbnailIcon = new ImageIcon(getScaledImage(imageIcon.getImage(), 25 , 25));
    jLabel1.setIcon(thumbnailIcon);
```

and here is code for resize image

```
private Image getScaledImage(Image srcImg, int w, int h){

    BufferedImage resizedImg = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g2 = resizedImg.createGraphics();

    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);

    g2.drawImage(srcImg, 0, 0, w, h, null);

    g2.dispose();
    return resizedImg;
}
```

but after resizing image and using this code the result is this! :

[image]

how can I have desired image on my JLabel??

regards, 
sajad

Comment: Is there a reason not to use [Image.getScaledInstance](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance(int,%20int,%20int)) for scaling your image?

Comment: So thank you ! this little words solved the problem !

Comment: If you don't mind me asking. I have used Java a lot and have looked into building custom components but what are all the parts and pieces that have to be in a custom JComponent to do the coding the correct way. I read a lot of things, but this topic seems to have a lot of different answers. If I wanted to start at ground zero and build a JLabel and add my own custom properties to it how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that when you create the scaled image, you use `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB` for your new image, and transparency gets rendered as black with just `TYPE_INT_RGB`.

In order to keep transparency, you need to replace that with `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB`, since you need an alpha component.

However, calling [Image.getScaledInstance](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance%28int,%20int,%20int%29) on `imageIcon`'s image will return a scaled image, already with an alpha component, and you can pass it rendering hints to play with the quality of the scaled image, doing essentially the same as your `getScaledImage` function, but with less of the hassle.